# How to scan a value from a string knowing the type but not the format specifier (without iostream)

Tags: c++

I have a string and I need to parse/scan a value from it. The code will know what type the value is, but not what format specifier should be used. Is there a way to parse the value without building a lookup table of every type and their associated format specifier?

I cannot use cin as this is an embedded application and adding iostream causes the program size to exceed the available flash.

Edit: Some code, for clarification.

I have a macro that looks something like this:

```c
#define ITEMS(ENTRY) \
    ENTRY(nameOne,   uint8_t,  1  ) \
    ENTRY(nameTwo,   int16_t, -1  ) \
    ENTRY(nameThree, char,    '1' ) \
```

Each entry in the table represents a piece of data. Additional macros are used to create non-volatile storage for each item, and to generate functions that can be used to get or set the values. Using these macros, rather than writing the code manually, means I can add and change entries in just one place with no risk of things getting out of sync. (Like changing the type of an entry in the function that creates the storage, but not in the function that gets the value.)

What I'm trying to do currently is create a text interface that can be used to set these values. The user would specify which value they want to set, then type in the desired value, and the code will parse that value and call the setter.

Here's what a simple example might look like:

```c
#define SET_ALL_ITEMS(name, type, defaultValue) \
{ \
   cout << "Input a value for " << #name << " : "; \
   type value; \
   cin >> value; \
   Setter(name, &value); \
   cout << endl; \
}
```

I believe that example would work. If you specified the values 20, 300, and 'f' I would expect the output to look like:

```
Input a value for nameOne : 20
Input a value for nameTwo : 300
Input a value for nameThree : f
```

However, I can't use `cin` because `iostream` is too heavy for this particular embedded target, so I need to stick with `scanf` style functions.

One possible option would be to create a Get Value function and overload it with the different types I need. I could also use typeid to make a switch/case or if/else if chain that returns a string with the correct format specifier in it. Both those ideas seem clumsy to me though. I'd like to know if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: what do you mean with "know the type, but not the format specifier" ? If you know the type you also know what format specifier to use with `scanf`, no?

Comment: You could write a parsing function for each type. If you could use either overloads or template specializations to make it easier to use, but you can just write functions with different names for each types. Edit : I'm not entirely confident I understand the problem.

Comment: Getting very close to an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: If you are severely limited on code space then you probably don't want to have a bunch of generic code ...